# Including Tensorflow Lite for Microcontrollers inside of project results in include errors

Tags: c++, tensorflow, makefile, embedded, tensorflow-lite

Im trying to include Tensorflow Lite for Microcontrollers inside of a C++ project with libDaisy (A HAL for the Electrosmith Daisy Seed Dev Board - A Dev Board based on the STM32H7 MCU). And I'm running into this issue where Tensorflow tries to import some other files but can't. It seems to be due to the usage of absolute paths because if I change them to relative paths it works but tensorflow has hundreds of imports so it is not practical todo that by hand. For example here is an error I get when including Tensorflow:

```
DataInference/RainPredictor/../../tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h:18:10: fatal error: tensorflow/lite/micro/compatibility.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include "tensorflow/lite/micro/compatibility.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can fix this by changing this include within Tensorflow from:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/compatibility.h"
```

to:

```
#include "compatibility.h"
```

but I would have to do this for every include inside of Tensorflow to fix all of these errors which is obviously impractical. Im assuming there is some Makefile magic or compiler setting I need to enable to allow the usage of absolute paths inside of my C++ project that I don't know about. And I can't seem to find anything with Google or in the C++ or Make docs. So could anyone enlighten me on this subject?

### Extra information:

#### Project structure:

- libDaisy/
- daisySP/
- Firmware/

  - Firmware.cpp
  - tensorflow/

    - ...
  - DataInference/

    - RainPredictor/

      - model.h
      - rain_predictor.cpp
  - (Nonrelevant files) ...
  - Makefile

#### Makefile contents:

```
# Project Name
TARGET = Firmware

# Sources
CPP_SOURCES = Firmware.cpp 

LDFLAGS += -u _printf_float

# Library Locations
LIBDAISY_DIR = ../libDaisy
DAISYSP_DIR = ../DaisySP
TENSORFLOW_DIR = ./tensorflow
TENSORFLOW_ROOT := ./tensorflow

# Core location, and generic makefile.
SYSTEM_FILES_DIR = $(LIBDAISY_DIR)/core
include $(SYSTEM_FILES_DIR)/Makefile
```

#### rain_predictor.cpp contents:

```
#include "../../tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
#include "../../tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "../../tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"
#include "model.h"

void predict_rain_intensity() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by making sure that the `tensorflow` directory is in the include path of the project. Usually there is a `CPP_FLAGS` (or similar) variable in your makefile (`$(SYSTEM_FILES_DIR)/Makefile` in your case), which you can append some include paths to:

`CPP_FLAGS += -Itensorflow`

Then add this just before the `LDFLAGS += -u _printf_float` line.